# Number converted to dictionary in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, debugging, numbering, regionalization, typecast

When reducing an image to number on it's geographical coordinates, the code does return a number, which is what should happen.

```
var accum = ETo.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
var accumNum = accum.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.sum(),geom,30);
accumNum = accumNum.getNumber('Potential_Evaporation_Rate_surface_6_Hour_Average_sum');
print('accum:', accumNum);
```

Resulting in the following print:

[image]

However, when I try to perform any other basic calculations such as an addition, it prints a weird string of code which doesn't contain the number at all.

```
print('accum:', 5 + accumNum);
```

Resulting print from previous operation:
[image]

This only concatinates the 5 to the string of code description returned by the operation.

The problem also happens when I try to set a label to the value of accumNum. However, in this case I can't display the number at all even without performing any calculations.

The only thing I need is to get the actual value from the reduced region.
Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is asking for a client-side operation (`+`) with inputs that are a client side object (`5`) and a server-side object (`accumNum`). Because of this mix, the result concatenates the client side object and the definition of server-side object (i.e. the part starting with `ee.Number`)

Instead, you can specify that the computation is done server-side by using [ee.Image.add()](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#eeimageadd). For example:

```js
print('accum:', ee.Image(5).add(accumNum));
```

For more information, see the [Client vs. Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server) section of the Earth Engine docs.

Comment: Great, I will use the server sive operations to perform this calculations.
For the second issue, do you know by any chance how I may be able to print the resulting value of accumNum into a panel? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Okay, I found out in the doc you provided I could use .getInfo() to retrieve data from the object in server. Thank you!